# VIM editor issue -- left right up & down arrows not working as expected

Tags: vim

My vim misbehaves. After pressing `esc + i` to insert text, i can't use left, right, top and down arrow keys of to traverse through a word. Kindly help me how do i resolve.. Also i can't see any syntax also being highlighted for my C file.

Comment: What platform? If this is on *nix it is probably a terminal issue.

Comment: Please provide more info on your platform, vim version, plugin, .vimrc. Otherwise it's impossible for us to tell where goes wrong

Comment: It sounds like `compatible` is on.

Answer (score 2):

> After pressing esc + i to insert a text : can't Using left , right , top & down arrow keys of keyboard to traverse thru a word.

Isn't this proper behaviour anyhow? You should use hjkl instead.
However, check your vimrc file to see if they have been unmapped.

> I can't see any syntax also being highlighted for my C file.

Enable syntax highlighting via `syntax on` in your vimrc file, or enter it as a command.